# Why would elements in a union be unaligned

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, unions

I've spent a couple hours trying to make sense of the results of a quick mockup I made for an application I am working on.  Here is what I am trying to do.  I have an incoming message, which among other things has a 512 bit field which can have multiple forms depending on its type and needs to be translated to usable data.  The first type results in the 4 x 32-bit words originating from the little endian LSB

```
|31                             0|
|-------------word1--------------|
|-------------word2--------------|
|-------------word3--------------|
|-------------word4--------------|
|-------------unused-------------|
 ...
|-------------unused-------------|
512
```

The second is significantly larger and has 4 x 128 bit words but still occupies the same overall space

```
|31                             0|
|-------------word1--------------|
|----------word1 cont.-----------|
|----------word1 cont.-----------|
|----------word1 cont.-----------|
|-------------word2--------------|
|----------word2 cont.-----------|
|----------word2 cont.-----------|
|----------word2 cont.-----------|
|-------------word3--------------|
|----------word3 cont.-----------|
|----------word3 cont.-----------|
|----------word1 cont.-----------|
|-------------word4--------------|
|----------word4 cont.-----------|
|----------word4 cont.-----------|
|----------word4 cont.-----------|
```

I am attempting to make a class that processes this into 4 accessible void* fields, regardless of if they are type 1 and convertible to a unsigned integer or 128 bit of void data.  Here is the code.

The first header is just common structures.  I attempted to minimize bit shifting by using unions.

```
// Common.hpp 
#ifndef COMMON_HPP
#define COMMON_HPP
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstddef>

enum WaveFormType
{
    TYPE1, 
    TYPE2
};
 
enum CommandWordEnum
{
    COMMAND1, 
    COMMAND2, 
    COMMAND3, 
    COMMAND4
};

// 384 + 32 + 32 + 32 + 32 = 512 bits
struct Type1CommandWord
{
    uint32_t unused[12];
    uint32_t word[4];
};

// 128 + 128 + 128 + 128 = 512 bits
struct Type2CommandWord
{
    uint32_t word1[4];
    uint32_t word2[4];
    uint32_t word3[4];
    uint32_t word4[4];
};
 
union CommandWordData
{
    uint8_t buffer[64];
    Type1CommandWord type1CommandWord;
    Type2CommandWord type2CommandWord;
};

#endif /* COMMON_HPP */
```

The second class is a mockup of the incoming message.  In reality it is a very large message, but at the moment, these fields are the ones I am concerned about.

```
// Message.hpp
#ifndef MESSAGE_HPP
#define MESSAGE_HPP
#include <cstdint>
#include "Common.hpp"

//Test Message
struct Message
{
    uint8_t data[64];
    WaveFormType waveFormType;
};

#endif /* MESSAGE_HPP */
```

The next class is the actual receiver class

```
// CommandReceiver.hpp
#ifndef COMMAND_RECEIVER_HPP
#define COMMAND_RECEIVER_HPP

#include "Common.hpp"
#include "Message.hpp"
#include <cstdlib>

class CommandReceiver
{
    public:
    CommandReceiver(Message &_message);
    
    virtual ~CommandReceiver() = default;
   
    WaveFormType getWaveFormType() const;
 
    size_t getCommandWordSize() const;
   
    void *getCommandWord(CommandWordEnum cmdWordEnum) const;
   
    private:
    CommandWordData commandWordData;
    WaveFormType waveFormType;  
};

#endif /* COMMAND_RECEIVER_HPP */
```

and the definition

```
// CommandReceiver.cpp
#include "CommandReceiver.hpp"
#include <string.h>

CommandReceiver::CommandReceiver(Message &_message)
: waveFormType(_message.waveFormType)
{
       memset(
            this->commandWordData.buffer,
            0,
            sizeof(commandWordData.buffer));
       
        memcpy(
            this->commandWordData.buffer,
            &_message.data,
            sizeof(this->commandWordData.buffer));    
}
   
WaveFormType CommandReceiver::getWaveFormType() const
{
    return waveFormType;
}
 
size_t CommandReceiver::getCommandWordSize() const
{
    return((waveFormType == TYPE2)
        ? sizeof(this->commandWordData.type2CommandWord.word1)
            : sizeof(this->commandWordData.type1CommandWord.word[1]));   
}
   
void *CommandReceiver::getCommandWord(CommandWordEnum cmdWordEnum) const
{
    void * cmdPtr = (void*)malloc(this->getCommandWordSize());
    switch(cmdWordEnum)
    {
        case COMMAND1:
            if(this->waveFormType == TYPE2)
            {
                memcpy(
                    cmdPtr,
                    this->commandWordData.type2CommandWord.word2,
                    this->getCommandWordSize());
            }
            else
            {
                memcpy(
                    cmdPtr,
                    &this->commandWordData.type1CommandWord.word[1],
                    this->getCommandWordSize());
            }
        break;
            
    case COMMAND2:
        if(this->waveFormType == TYPE2)
        {
            memcpy(
                cmdPtr,
                &this->commandWordData.type2CommandWord.word2,
                this->getCommandWordSize());
        }
        else
        {
            memcpy(
                cmdPtr,
                &this->commandWordData.type1CommandWord.word[2],
                this->getCommandWordSize());
        }
        break;
        
    case COMMAND3:
        if(this->waveFormType == TYPE2)
        {
            memcpy(
                cmdPtr,
                &this->commandWordData.type2CommandWord.word3,
                this->getCommandWordSize());
        }
        else
        {
            memcpy(
                cmdPtr,
                &this->commandWordData.type1CommandWord.word[3],
                this->getCommandWordSize());
        }
        break;
        
    case COMMAND4:
            if(this->waveFormType == TYPE2)
            {
                memcpy(
                    cmdPtr,
                    &this->commandWordData.type2CommandWord.word4,
                    this->getCommandWordSize());
            }
            else
            {
                memcpy(
                    cmdPtr,
                    &this->commandWordData.type1CommandWord.word[4],
                    this->getCommandWordSize());
            }
            break;
            
        default:
            // memcpy(
                // cmdPtr,
                // nullptr,
                // this->getCommandWordSize());
            break;
        }
        return cmdPtr;    
}
```

finally the main file which I made a few simple tests.
What I am confused about is why a cannot get addresses to
align.  See below.

```
#include "CommandReceiver.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cassert>
 
//test
int main()
{
    // Confirm substructures are the correct size
    assert(sizeof(Type1CommandWord) == 512 / 8);
    assert(sizeof(Type2CommandWord) == 512 / 8);

    // Set up tests
    Message msg;
    memset(&msg.data, 0, sizeof(msg.data));
    msg.data[60] = 0xDE;
    msg.data[61] = 0xAD;
    msg.data[62] = 0xC0;
    msg.data[63] = 0xDE;
    msg.waveFormType = TYPE1;
   
    // Call the constructor
    CommandReceiver cmdRec(msg);
    
    // Confirm values copied in constructor match
    assert(cmdRec.commandWordData.buffer[60] == 0xDE);
    assert(cmdRec.commandWordData.buffer[61] == 0xAD);
    assert(cmdRec.commandWordData.buffer[62] == 0xC0);
    assert(cmdRec.commandWordData.buffer[63] == 0xDE);
    
    std::cout << "0x"<< &cmdRec.commandWordData.buffer + 60 << "\n";
    std::cout << "0x"<< &cmdRec.commandWordData.buffer + 61 << "\n";
    std::cout << "0x"<< &cmdRec.commandWordData.type1CommandWord + (32 * 4) << "\n";
```

The bottom line is it is not working and the problem is fairly early on.  I just cannot figure out why.  Here is the output:

```
0x0x7ffc3139f2e8
0x0x7ffc3139f328
0x0x7ffc313a03e8
```

The first two fields should be adjacent characters of an unsigned char array. so I would expect them to be 1 byte off, not 744 bytes.

The third field should be equal to the first but instead it is 1100 bytes off.  I'm obviously missing something big.

What am I missing? I'd also be interested in suggestions about better ways of doing this. However, the endpoints have to remain the same.

Comment: I have a feeling you want `static_cast<void*>(cmdRec.commandWordData.buffer + 60)` or `static_cast<void*>(&cmdRec.commandWordData.buffer[60])` instead of what you have. `0x0x7ffc3139f328 - 0x0x7ffc3139f2e8 == 64` so I'm unsure where 744 came from.

Comment: That was what I tried first. I thought you could do that but I had trouble casting the pointer.   error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘uint32_t*’ {aka ‘unsigned int*’} [-fpermissive]
   19 |     uint32_t *type1Word4Ptr = static_cast<void*>(buffer + 60);

Comment: I’m pretty sure you’re printing the address of a temporary pointer and then one past a temporary pointer variable which, with 64 bit pointers adds up. Try just `cout << arr + 60` on my phone so I’m not typing out your long name and the so app still doesn’t copy+paste. Also, I think your life would be easier if you gave up on unions and memcpy and wrote something a little more modern and maintainable.

Comment: What would a modern maintainable way of removing chunks of void data from a bit stream without copying memory, unions or pointer math?

Comment: I’ll admit, I didn’t go over all the code (I’m on a phone and it’s not exactly a MRE) general speaking when I see code similar to the above it’s people trying too hard instead of using the tools available in the standard library or even other existing libraries. I made some assumptions that may or may not be correct, but I stand by it as good advice, even if you are or aren’t currently following it. That being said if I’m off base or my comment bothered you, I do apologize.

Comment: Thank you,  If there is an easier way to do what I am trying to do, I am all about it.  Unfortunately I do not believe there is.  I thought unions would be the simplest approach but they don't seem to line up as I would expect them to.

Comment: @mreff555 did you try removing the `&` from your couts?

Comment: that doesn't compile because there is no overload for the '+' operator if I'm not working with a memory address.

Comment: `union` is now mostly only used to create [`variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

Answer (score 2):

With pointer arithmetic, type of pointer does count:

```
int* p = /*..*/;
char* c = reinterpret_cast<char*>(p);
int n = /*..*/;
assert(reinterpret_cast<char*>(p + n) == c + n * sizeof(int));
//                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So in your case

```
&cmdRec.commandWordData.type1CommandWord + (32 * 4)
```

"is"

```
reinterpret_cast<Type1CommandWord*>(
    reinterpret_cast<const char*>(
        &cmdRec.commandWordData.type1CommandWord
    ) + (32 * 4) * sizeof(Type1CommandWord)
)
```

and

`&cmdRec.commandWordData.buffer + 60` is not `&cmdRec.commandWordData.buffer[60]` but

`reinterpret_cast<uint8_t(*)[64]>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&cmdRec.commandWordData.buffer) + 60 * sizeof(uint8_t[64]))`